# C# Regex remove everything except \d+, one, nine and decimal point

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

How can i do something like this.

```
new Regex("([^\d+]|[^one]|[^nine]|[^,])").Replace("Fi10An,fONEy,Onineo", "");
```

I would get this:

```
10,one,nine
```

But i would get a empty string with my wrong regex above.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: You have a serious misconception: [] is a *character class*, it only matches a single character.

Comment: By what logic is `,` a decimal point here? You're using it as a list item separator, aren't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the opposite: match what you need and then take it from the string. For example:

```
Regex.Matches("Fi10An,fONEy,Onineo", @"(\d+|one|nine|,)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

And then combine the matches into one string. This would be the easiest and the clearest solution.

Comment: Yes its correct but issnt this possible with regex? :) I would learn something.

Comment: @PatrickB, well, maybe you could invent some regex to do the replace, but I'm not sure if this regex and the replace string would be simple and moreover, whether it would be possible to preserve the order of the words and maintain a dynamic length of the input string :)